# jconsole not detecting jboss eap 6.1

Tags: java, performance, jconsole, jboss-eap-6

We have recently migrated from Jboss 5.0 to Jboss6.1 EAP.

As part of performance monitoring,I want to connect Jconsole to the jboss process.
Whenever I try to run jconsole from the standalone server ,it doesnt detect the locally running Jboss process.

Upon some investigation I found that it happens only when I run Jboss as a service.       If I run it from the command prompt Jconsole is able to detect Jboss process.

I tried to google and found someone saying that I need to add below to expose Mbeans that are required by Jconsole.

```
<system-properties>
<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.ENABLE_MODELER" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

I have added above to standlaone.xml and run jboss as service but jconsole still doesnt detect jboss...
Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Did you run JConsole from `JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh`?

Comment: @PetrMensik  I tried both JBOSS_HOME/bin/Jconsole and JAVA_HOME/bin/Jconsole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue by doing below:

1. Set the remote connection URL as
   service:jmx:remoting-jmx://jbossHost:9999

   with the username : admin and password : admin@123

Basically I had to use remoting url instead of trying to find the local running process.
Users looking for this issue would find useful at this [Jboss forum Link](https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/01038333/#newCommentForm)